# Is it possible to automatically grab all FORM variables and values on HTML into Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm just getting started w/ AJAX/JS so forgive if this seems noobish.. (over 10 years of php and actionscript on my belt though)

I did look around but couldnt get answers to what i specifically wanted to do.

Like the title says, I wanted to the variable=values of the current form of the html document  into JS (for XMLHttpRequest processing)

If my form fields were numbered, say id1 id2 id3, etc i could loop through it. but unfortunately, they're not..

so is there like a JS function that just grabs all those form field var=values into the JS block of things?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It's not clear what you want exactly and especially what for, but maybe [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` which takes CSS selectors. Example (you can tweak to work with selects and filter out buttons - this is the idea because I don't know what your problem is (although you should figure it out yourself from here))

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    values.push(elems[i].value);
}
```

Comment: ahh i see what you mean .. didnt know about querySelectorAll('input') was available.. nice. i can loop through the fields this way :) tnx